# How to make playbook idempotent with raw module?

Tags: ansible

I have servers without python2 installed by default (the target servers are mainly under Alpine Linux) and i use the playbook below to fix that.

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: no
  pre_tasks:
      # Python is not installed by default
      - name: 'Install python'
        raw: apk --no-cache add python

  tasks:
      - name: 'Upgrade Operating System'
        apk:
                available: yes
                upgrade: yes

      - name: 'Install base software'
        apk:
                name: '{{ item }}'
                state: latest
        with_items:
                - tmux
                - vim
                - git
```

I use raw module because without python package installed i got this output :

```
TASK [Upgrade Operating System] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [172.16.160.254]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 172.16.160.254 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
```

Actually the playbook works fine but the state is 'changed=1' for every time 'Install python' tasks run.

Is it possible to make it idempotent (with play recap 'changed=0' and everything are 'ok=x') ?
If yes can you help me to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain, but I think it might already be almost idempotent because of how APK works.  Based on what I can tell, APK will return success without doing anything if you tell it to add a package that is already installed (at least, that's what it's doing when trying to install python2 on a system I've already got it installed on).  The only potential caveat is that it will upgrade the package if there is a newer version, but I don't think there is any way without embedding a shell script into the playbook that you can work around that (you would have to parse the output of `apk version` to figure out if it would update it or not).